# Scroll Bug in Elastic gird jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, elastic-grid

I'm using the [elastic grid plugin](http://demo.phapsu.com/jquery.elastic_grid/) to display my gallery.
I discoverd a bug in the plugin and I'm wondering how to fix it.

To recreate the bug:

1) click an image to reveal expanded details.

2) clicking on an image in a row below the current slide out causes the plugin to wrongly calulate the scroll. Clicking above the slide out seems to work fine.

Has anyone discoverd a solution to this bug? I've attached reference images

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Thanks for your time. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I found the bug. It was a single line that was causing a miss calculation of the height. 
For anyone else facing this error comment out the first `hidePreview();` line inside the `showPreview( $item )` function in the `elastic_grid.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. Sometimes the page would just scroll itself to the top.

I realized I was using a function(on document.ready()) which was acting upon the List-Categories before it was completely loaded.

See if you're doing something similar..
Let the Plugin Completely Load